# Wit.ai not recognizing the same sentence from different voices

Tags: voice-recognition, speech-to-text, wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm using speech-to-text API from wit.ai. I have setup my stories and intents successfully and tested with my voice. However, when I ask my friend to test the app, the API doesn't correctly catch the same sentences although we're both saying the same thing.

Is there a way to make wit.ai to understand voices from new users without explicitly training their voices on wit.ai webapp?